# GitHub - Repository state at specified time

Tags: git, github

I am beginner in using git versioning tool.

I would like to download repository state (files) at specified time (e.g. on 5.10.2013).
How can I do that ?

Comment: You should note that Git doesn't keep track of the _repository state_ at particular points in time. It knows when commits are created, but since that often happens in clones of the official repository (or whichever repository's state you're interested in) and only later pushed upstream the timestamp isn't very useful. Trying to identify repository state by timestamp is just not a very good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click "Commits" and look for a commit that was on that date. Now clone the repository to your computer and check out that commit.

Comment: What happens when there's merges either side of that date and there's multiple points in the commit history that are before and after that date?

Comment: You don't need to clone locally to checkout a commit. You can view a Github repo on a commit basis also.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 24):

As of May 2019 (not sure when this was introduced), you can simply add the date in the following format - `HEAD@{2019-04-29}` - in the place of the URL where the commit would usually belong.

Example: Here is a link to the react repo on a recent commit https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/95e06ac3d091b6746be80d13840884dc7894b01c

Replacing the commit hash with the date formatted as above [https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/HEAD@{2019-04-29}](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/HEAD@%7B2019-04-29%7D) will bring you to the React repo as it looked on April 29.

You can also compare commits based on time - see more info from Github's help docs here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/comparing-commits-across-time#comparisons-across-time

**UPDATE NOV. 2021:**
As mentioned in the comments below, this seems to now have a limit on the amount of days you can go back to (roughly 134 days in my experience).

The referenced Github help article also seems to have removed any mention of comparisons across time.

**UPDATE MARCH 2024:**
As per comments, seems to be working again.

Comment: This ultimately is a very helpful way to view a repo in github/GHE's web app, by date.

Comment: For some reason this only seems to work for dates within the last 583 days or so. Anything beyond that and I get a 404 error.

Comment: Works for me beyond that.
Example: https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/HEAD@%7B2017-04-29%7D

Comment: This no longer works.  It seems github disabled/removed it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's happening here. It let me go back to June 26 (So 134 days ago) but not further than that.

This works (a/o today) -> https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/HEAD@%7B2021-08-29%7D

But this doesn't -> https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/HEAD@%7B2021-06-25%7D

Comment: The limit might have been a GitHub bug. Both of the links above work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rev-list` command to search for commits it revers chronological order

```
git rev-list <branch-name> --max-count=1 --before=<timestamp>
```

For a concrete example.  The commit before Jan 10 2014 on my master branch

```
git rev-list master --max-count=1 --before=2014-10-01
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would very much recommend that you avoid using a date.  This is a very inexact way of looking at a repository at a certain point in time.  Instead, be exact, and pick a specific commit or tag.  Typically people want to revert back to a particular release, in which case there should be a tag.  You can list all available tags by typing `git tag`.

If you'd rather use a commit then use `git log` to find the commit.  This command supports a lot of options which you can view by typing `git help log`.  For example, on the `o-js` repo on GitHub `git log --oneline` produces:

```
10b5421 Add .npmignore to bower.json ignore list.
a7681b2 Update package.json for new CommonJS structure and add an .npmignore.
c9e3a52 Migrated everything to CommonJS format modules (no more hacks for the we
9af7a3d Lots of adjustments to reduce the minified size by several kilobytes.
c1c7bda Better error messaging across the board (no more "..." errors). Fixes #4
008871d Adjust exception throwing a bit to be more minification-friendly.
3bce458 Expose o.ucFirst to the public.
866d53e Added o.positiveIntType due to this type being a common case.
cc395d1 New CHANGES file format.
f26de19 Massage the CHANGES list a bit for the next release.
```

The hashes are actually 40 characters long, but `--oneline` just includes the first 7 characters, as do many other commands.  You can use the 40-character version or the 7-character version of the hash.

If you'd like to list commits around a certain date you can do:

```
git log --oneline --since=2013-05-05 --until=2013-05-15
```

You asked about being able to download the files.  This makes me think that you do not want to clone the repository, and instead just want a full snapshot in time of the repository at a certain point (without the `.git` directory).  This is done using the `git archive` command which takes a `tree-ish` value for the point in time.  Tags and commits work fine for this.

If you wanted a tar archive of the `o-js` repo for release `v0.0.6` you'd do:

```
git archive --output=o-js-0.0.6.tar v0.0.6
```

This creates `o-js-0.0.6.tar` in the current directory with all files at the state they were in when the `v0.0.6` tag was created.  Again, you can replace `v0.0.6` in the command with a commit hash and it will work just as well.

If you did not actually want just the files and instead wanted to rewind your git checkout to a point in time you'd do this instead:

```
git reset --hard v0.0.6
```

The `git reset` command is dangerous in inexperienced hands, so use it with caution.  This documentation about `git reset` is a great start:

http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html