# How to get the revision at a specific date, of a file from a Github repository?

Tags: date, github, commit, sha, revision

*How many of you* ever clicked on a Github link to a file version, just to find out that who made the link didn't care of putting a fixed commit sha (**or, protip:** simply pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>) when copying it from Github, and that the link is expired because now the `master` branch points to a different commit that at the time when the link was made, and the file was moved and changed in the meanwhile?

✋‍♀️‍♀️‍♂️‍♂️

I see...
So is there any Github url parameter *or* a way to specify the branch path, that would allow me to display the version of the branch **at a specific time in the past**?

Somethinge like https://github.com/repo/master/old/path/to/file`?date=2019-07-31T00:15:43+00:00`.

The alternative is to find out the date from the, let's say, Github issue's comment where you copied/clicked the link from and start to scroll through the branch's *Commits* pagination, until (almost at the last page..) you finally find the most recent commit closer to the date you found, so you can start to *Browse files* for the commit just found in order to get, after wasting 10/15 minutes, at the version of the file that the initial link author intended to actually lead to.

Or you need to ask an answer on SO.
Not really convenient.

Is there such a parameter supported by Github?

Comment: <kbd>P</kbd>? I though it was <kbd>Y</kbd>... https://help.github.com/en/articles/keyboard-shortcuts#source-code-browsing

Comment: @VonC you are right, my bad, I remembered wrong. Fixed, thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub - Repository state at specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345787/github-repository-state-at-specified-time)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `curl`, using the GitHub API, in order to [list commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository).

That particular API (`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits`) has a `until` parameter:

> Only commits before this date will be returned. This is a timestamp in ISO 8601 format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`.

The first commit listed would be the one you are looking for.
You can see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925280/6309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45269578/6309).